# How to debug kernel oops "Unable to handle kernel paging request"

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel

I changed some configuration and build a new uImage.
Then I move the new uImage to /boot
When I start the system, I find an oops in dmesg.
The system looks working well, except that "insmod xxx" can not be run.

I am not familiar with kernel, and don't know how to debug this.
In addition, I have set "CONFIG_FRAM_POINTER=y", but why the oops did not show the "Call Trace"?

```
[    4.572000] Loading modules backported from Linux version v4.4.2-0-g1cb8570
[    4.572000] Backport generated by backports.git v4.4.2-1-0-gbec4037
[    4.572000] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 009b7004
[    4.572000] pgd = e497c000
[    4.572000] [009b7004] *pgd=00000000
[    4.572000] Internal error: Oops: 5 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM
[    4.572000] Modules linked in: compat(O)
[    4.572000] CPU: 7    Tainted: G           O  (3.4.39-s5p6818 #7)
[    4.572000] PC is at module_put+0x58/0x104
[    4.572000] LR is at get_parent_ip+0x14/0x30
[    4.572000] pc : [<c00a37c8>]    lr : [<c007d6a8>]    psr: 600e0013
[    4.572000] sp : e49d9ec8  ip : e49d8000  fp : e49d9ee4
[    4.572000] r10: bf0050d8  r9 : e490a264  r8 : 00000c9b
[    4.572000] r7 : e49d8008  r6 : c00a6704  r5 : bf005090  r4 : bf005090
[    4.572000] r3 : 00000004  r2 : c0994c44  r1 : c09368f0  r0 : 009b7000
[    4.572000] Flags: nZCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
[    4.572000] Control: 10c5383d  Table: 6497c06a  DAC: 00000015
[    4.572000] PC: 0xc00a3748:
[    4.572000] 3748  e244401c eb044cc9 e1550007 e5960000 e2855001 1afffff8 eb08bcbb e1a00006
[    4.572000] 3768  eb027bb5 e89da8f0 e1a0c00d e92dd8f0 e24cb004 e52de004 e8bd4000 e2505000
[    4.572000] 3788  e1a0600e 089da8f0 e3a00001 ebff67ca f57ff05f e1a0300d e30618f0 e3c37d7f
[    4.572000] 37a8  e34c1093 e3c7c03f e595316c e59c0014 e3042c44 e34c2099 e2833004 e7910100
[    4.572000] 37c8  e7931000 e2811001 e7831000 e5923018 e3530000 1a00000a e5953000 e3530002
[    4.572000] 37e8  0a00001e e3a00001 ebff67ec e3c7703f e5973000 e3130002 089da8f0 eb16f431
[    4.572000] 3808  e89da8f0 e59c3004 e2833001 e58c3004 e5924024 e3540000 0a000007 e5943000
[    4.572000] 3828  e5940004 e1a01005 e1a02006 e12fff33 e5b43008 e3530000 1afffff8 e3c7303f
[    4.572000] LR: 0xc007d628:
[    4.572000] d628  e5933044 e12fff33 e1a00004 eb178f2f eb01faaf e7973106 e0855003 e595248c
[    4.572000] d648  e5953490 e1520003 0a000005 e3a03000 e5c434c0 e1a00004 e1a01006 eb00255f
[    4.572000] d668  e89da9f8 e5953014 e3530000 1afffff6 e59535bc e16f3f13 e1a032a3 eafffff3
[    4.572000] d688  e1a00004 ebfff4fa eaffffc3 e1a0c00d e92dd818 e24cb004 e1a04000 eb0091a3
[    4.572000] d6a8  e3500000 0a000002 e3a04000 e1a00004 eb00919e e1a00004 e89da818 e1a0c00d
[    4.572000] d6c8  e92dd830 e24cb004 e52de004 e8bd4000 e3043850 e1a05000 e34c309b e5933000
[    4.572000] d6e8  e3530000 e1a0300d e3c34d7f e3c4203f e5923004 1a000013 e3530000 ba00001a
[    4.572000] d708  e0833000 e6ef1073 e5823004 e35100f4 9a00000e eb098350 e3500000 0a00000b
[    4.572000] SP: 0xe49d9e48:
[    4.572000] 9e48  c007d854 c007d6a0 600e0013 00000000 e49d9e7c c00a37c8 600e0013 ffffffff
[    4.572000] 9e68  e49d9eb4 00000c9b e49d9ee4 e49d9e80 c000efd8 c00083e8 009b7000 c09368f0
[    4.572000] 9e88  c0994c44 00000004 bf005090 bf005090 c00a6704 e49d8008 00000c9b e490a264
[    4.572000] 9ea8  bf0050d8 e49d9ee4 e49d8000 e49d9ec8 c007d6a8 c00a37c8 600e0013 ffffffff
[    4.572000] 9ec8  bf005090 00000000 e490a240 00000001 e49d9fa4 e49d9ee8 c00a6704 c00a377c
[    4.572000] 9ee8  bf00509c 00007fff 00000000 e49d9f00 c007d854 c0997070 ef80cc10 ef80cc38
[    4.572000] 9f08  ef80c580 bf0051ec 00000001 b6ec063c e49d8028 bf0050d8 e49d9f64 bf003070
[    4.572000] 9f28  00000003 bf003088 0000003b 00000000 00000000 ef804000 00008c60 ef80c580
[    4.572000] IP: 0xe49d7f80:
[    4.572000] 7f80  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    4.572000] 7fa0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    4.572000] 7fc0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    4.572000] 7fe0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    4.572000] 8000  00000000 00000003 00000000 e4c378c0 c0949a6c 00000007 00000015 c12d59c0
[    4.572000] 8020  e4c378c0 e5905400 00000000 e51cf400 00000001 c09368f0 e49d9b1c e49d9a70
[    4.572000] 8040  c0660100 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 01010000 00000000
[    4.572000] 8060  b6f03870 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    4.572000] FP: 0xe49d9e64:
[    4.572000] 9e64  ffffffff e49d9eb4 00000c9b e49d9ee4 e49d9e80 c000efd8 c00083e8 009b7000
[    4.572000] 9e84  c09368f0 c0994c44 00000004 bf005090 bf005090 c00a6704 e49d8008 00000c9b
[    4.572000] 9ea4  e490a264 bf0050d8 e49d9ee4 e49d8000 e49d9ec8 c007d6a8 c00a37c8 600e0013
[    4.572000] 9ec4  ffffffff bf005090 00000000 e490a240 00000001 e49d9fa4 e49d9ee8 c00a6704
[    4.572000] 9ee4  c00a377c bf00509c 00007fff 00000000 e49d9f00 c007d854 c0997070 ef80cc10
[    4.572000] 9f04  ef80cc38 ef80c580 bf0051ec 00000001 b6ec063c e49d8028 bf0050d8 e49d9f64
[    4.572000] 9f24  bf003070 00000003 bf003088 0000003b 00000000 00000000 ef804000 00008c60
[    4.572000] 9f44  ef80c580 ef80983d ef80a77c 000051f8 000056a8 00000000 00000000 0000002a
[    4.572000] R1: 0xc0936870:
[    4.572000] 6870  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    4.572000] 6890  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    4.572000] 68b0  000000fa 00009000 0000000f c12dc100 c12dc0c0 c12dc080 00000009 c1294000
[    4.572000] 68d0  00000008 0000002c c12dc000 c12dc040 00000001 00001000 00000000 00000007
[    4.572000] 68f0  00978000 00981000 0098a000 00993000 0099c000 009a5000 009ae000 009b7000
[    4.572000] 6910  00010a00 00000001 00065e3b 0007ffff 00000000 00000032 0000fffa 00000001
[    4.572000] 6930  00000000 e582f680 c0652694 c014b9d4 c01482a4 00000000 c014bd70 c0148288
[    4.572000] 6950  c014815c 00000000 00000000 c0146cdc 00000000 00000000 00000003 00000001
[    4.572000] R2: 0xc0994bc4:
[    4.572000] 4bc4  00000000 00000000 c080b778 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 c080b78c
[    4.572000] 4be4  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 c080b7b0 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    4.572000] 4c04  00000000 c080b7c4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 c080b820 00000000
[    4.572000] 4c24  00000000 00000000 00000000 c080b838 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    4.572000] 4c44  c080b868 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 c080b85c 00000000 00000000
[    4.572000] 4c64  00000000 00000000 c080b874 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 c080b880
[    4.572000] 4c84  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 c080b84c 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    4.572000] 4ca4  00000000 c080b88c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 c080b8a0 00000000
[    4.572000] R6: 0xc00a6684:
[    4.572000] 6684  e51b0068 eb02326a e3760a01 e1a04005 8afffbfd e59f01dc e3a01001 e1a02004
[    4.572000] 66a4  ebff352c e59400bc e3500000 0a000003 ebfd87e4 e2505000 ba000024 1a00030e
[    4.572000] 66c4  e3a05000 e59f01b0 e1a03005 e5845000 e3a01003 e3a02001 ebff484f e1a01005
[    4.572000] 66e4  e1a02004 e59f018c ebff351a ebff3b93 e59f01ac eb16e2a8 e1a00004 ebfff41a
[    4.572000] 6704  e1a00004 eb08aa96 e5941114 e1a00004 e594210c e594311c e5841110 e5842108
[    4.572000] 6724  e5843118 e59410c0 ebfff9f0 e58450c0 e58450c8 e58450d8 e58450d0 e59f0160
[    4.572000] 6744  eb16e20f e1a00005 e24bd028 e89daff0 e3a06002 e5846000 eb00ac24 e1a00004
[    4.572000] 6764  ebfff401 e1a01006 e1a02004 e59f0104 ebff34f8 e1a00004 ebfff9ea e59f00f8
[    4.572000] R7: 0xe49d7f88:
[    4.572000] 7f88  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    4.572000] 7fa8  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    4.572000] 7fc8  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    4.572000] 7fe8  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000003
[    4.572000] 8008  00000000 e4c378c0 c0949a6c 00000007 00000015 c12d59c0 e4c378c0 e5905400
[    4.572000] 8028  00000000 e51cf400 00000001 c09368f0 e49d9b1c e49d9a70 c0660100 00000000
[    4.572000] 8048  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 01010000 00000000 b6f03870 00000000
[    4.572000] 8068  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    4.572000] R9: 0xe490a1e4:
[    4.572000] a1e4  30936305 e4c952e0 00000000 00000000 81240002 000030c4 00000000 00000001
[    4.572000] a204  00000000 e4a1ed00 e4a1e740 e490a1d0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    4.572000] a224  2fe0e316 e4c95304 00000000 00000000 81240002 000030c5 00000000 e490a280
[    4.572000] a244  00000001 e49cf7c0 00000124 00000024 bf00304c c00a39f8 00000000 00000000
[    4.572000] a264  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 e490a2c0
[    4.572000] a284  e490a284 e490a284 bf0050d8 00000000 c095f654 e490a340 00000001 00000003
[    4.572000] a2a4  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 65746f6e
[    4.572000] a2c4  00000073 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    4.572000] Process systemd-modules (pid: 204, stack limit = 0xe49d82f0)
[    4.572000] Stack: (0xe49d9ec8 to 0xe49da000)
[    4.572000] 9ec0:                   bf005090 00000000 e490a240 00000001 e49d9fa4 e49d9ee8
[    4.572000] 9ee0: c00a6704 c00a377c bf00509c 00007fff 00000000 e49d9f00 c007d854 c0997070
[    4.572000] 9f00: ef80cc10 ef80cc38 ef80c580 bf0051ec 00000001 b6ec063c e49d8028 bf0050d8
[    4.572000] 9f20: e49d9f64 bf003070 00000003 bf003088 0000003b 00000000 00000000 ef804000
[    4.572000] 9f40: 00008c60 ef80c580 ef80983d ef80a77c 000051f8 000056a8 00000000 00000000
[    4.572000] 9f60: 0000002a 0000002b 00000021 00000000 00000015 00000000 00000002 00000000
[    4.572000] 9f80: b6d57000 b6f1de90 00000080 c000f6c4 e49d8000 00000000 00000000 e49d9fa8
[    4.572000] 9fa0: c000f480 c00a55dc 00000000 b6d57000 b6d57000 00008c60 b6ec063c 00000026
[    4.572000] 9fc0: 00000000 b6d57000 b6f1de90 00000080 00020000 b6f1de68 b6f1e338 00000000
[    4.572000] 9fe0: b6e0efc1 beed43a0 b6eba953 b6e0efc8 000e0030 b6d57000 00000000 00000000
[    4.572000] [<c00a37c8>] (module_put+0x58/0x104) from [<c00a6704>] (sys_init_module+0x1134/0x1eac)
[    4.572000] [<c00a6704>] (sys_init_module+0x1134/0x1eac) from [<c000f480>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x30)
[    4.572000] Code: e3042c44 e34c2099 e2833004 e7910100 (e7931000) 
[    4.572000] ---[ end trace 258de705688d7d39 ]---
[    4.572000] note: systemd-modules[204] exited with preempt_count 1
```

Comment: At the end of the log you show there is call trace (consisted from 2 entries). What else you are looking for?